# Linear programming problem : minimise number of truck used

Tags: integer, linear-programming, cplex, opl

I need to modelize with a Linear Integer Program the following problem :

We need to carry n different products from a factory to a warehouse. Each product has its own weight (the element i has a weight wi<W). We are using trucks with a maximum weight capacity of W, the objective is to minimize the number of truck used.

I tried different way but I always have trouble to modelize the number of truck in the objective function.

I used a variable Yij which equals  1 if the truck i carries the item j,  0 otherwise and managed to write the different constraints. But I can't find how to count the number of trucks used with that variable.

If anyone has any suggestion it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome @Johnn1xy. Adding your formulation to the question would help in adding clarity and showing you what should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Yij` is a `rectangular matrix of size (m=items, n=trucks)` full of *binary-variables* like:

```
truck    0    1   2
item 0   x00  x   x
item 1   x10  x   x
item 2   x20  x   x
item 3   x30  x   x
```

you can create additional *binary variables* `t_used_0` (shown for `truck_0` only) like:

```
sum(Yij_column_0) <= m * t_used_0

    <-> x00 + x10 + x20 + x30 <= 4 * t_used_0

sum(Yij_column_0) >= t_used_0

    <-> x00 + x10 + x20 + x30 >= t_used_0
```

You then have `n` auxiliary binary-variables `t_used_i` which you can sum up in your *objective*.

(There is lots of degree of freedom in those *linearizations* (e.g. equivalence vs. implication only) which somewhat explains why user abc asked for more information. In general, you *exploit* everything possible.)